# How To Represent Multiplication In PHP

Tags: php, html

It is possible to represent mathematical multiplication steps in php. I have tried But I am unable to show the complete steps i have just get the sum and carry and the result I want to get the result.

for example:-

```
    4  2  0
     x 5 2
  -----------
     8 4 0
   2 1 0 0
 -------------
  2  9 4 0
```

this is my php code.

```
        $data = array(
    'digit1' => $_POST['value1'],
    'digit2' => $_POST['value2'],
    'digit3' => $_POST['value3'],
    'digit4' => $_POST['value4'],
    'digit5' => $_POST['value5']
);

# ------------------------------------------------------------
$product = $data['digit5'] * $data['digit3'];
$a = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit5'] * $data['digit2']) + $carry;
$b = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit5'] * $data['digit1']) + $carry;
$c = $product;
#-------------------------------------------------------------
$product = $data['digit4'] * $data['digit3'];
$d = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit4'] * $data['digit2']) + $carry;
$e = $product % 10;
$carry = floor($product / 10);

$product = ($data['digit4'] * $data['digit1']) + $carry;
$f = $product;
#-------------------------------------------------------------
$x = intval($c . $b . $a);
$y = intval($f . $e . $d) * 10;
#-------------------------------------------------------------

echo sprintf("%' 10d\n", $c ." " .$b . " ".$a);
echo "<br/>";
echo sprintf("%' 9d\n",  $f. " " .$e ." ". $d);
echo "<br/>";
echo "----------\n";
echo "<br/>";
echo sprintf("%' 10d\n", $x + $y);
```

this is my html

```
<form method="POST" action="ui.php">
<input type="textbox" name="value1"/>
<input type="textbox" name="value2"/>
<input type="textbox" name="value3"/>
<input type="textbox" name="value4"/>
<input type="textbox" name="value5"/>
<input type="Submit" name="Submit"/>
```

Comment: is there a reason for collecting the numbers one by one instead of just two complete numbers?

Comment: I want to show in this format @RST

Comment: Show and collect is not the same thing. Why not just two input  fields, one for (in this example) 420, one for 52.

Comment: ok not a problem if it solve by two input fields. I want to show each step mathematically of multiplication @RST

Answer (score 2):

If you use str_split() to convert the multiplicand into an array of values, you can use the pow() function to work out each line.

```
<?php
$multiplier = 420;
$multiplicand = 52;
$result = $multiplier * $multiplicand;
$pad_max = strlen($result);

$multiplicand_values = str_split($multiplicand);

echo str_pad($multiplier, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo str_pad("x" . $multiplicand, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo str_pad("-", $pad_max, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;


for($i = 0; null !== ($digit = array_pop($multiplicand_values)); ++$i)
{
    echo str_pad($multiplier * $digit * pow(10, $i), $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
}

echo str_pad("-", $pad_max, "-", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
echo str_pad($result, $pad_max, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: There is an extra 0 of `2100`

Comment: 420 x 52 = 21840

I think the original question has incorrect mathematics

Comment: I have done phpfiddle for the code and there is line `21000` while it should be `2100`

Comment: Unless I've completely misunderstood I think `21000` is correct. 

420 x 52 = 840 + 21000

Comment: That's what I saw when I ran the code. I think it's right! Isn't the example in the question incorrect?

Comment: I don't think it is meant to be 5 x 400 - I think it is meant to be 50 x 400.

Comment: Please try to multiply 52 * 420 using a pencil and a paper. First 2 * 420, second 5 * 420 finally sum the two results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$a = intval( $_POST['value1'] . $_POST['value2'] . $_POST['value3']);
$b = array(
    1 => intval( $_POST['value5']),
    10 => intval( $_POST['value4']),
    );

    echo $a . '<br />';
    echo 'x ' . $b[10] . $b[1] .'<br />';
    echo '--------------';

   foreach ($b as $key => $number) {
     echo $key*$number*$a . '<br />';
   }
   echo '--------------<br />';
   echo $a * (($b[10] * 10) + $b[1]);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. I made some changes because 4 and 5 where swapped around

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$b' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' on line 44

Comment: this line contains error in the code echo 'x ' . $b[10]$b[1] .'<br />';

Comment: you can put a dot between them